# I am using crontab for magento task and it providing this error

Tags: magento-1.9

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'dilsebol2.wd_feed' doesn't exist

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dilsebol2.wd_feed' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `wd_feed`' in /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `wd_fe...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `wd_fe...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(171): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DESCRIBE `wd_fe...')
#6 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1596): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('wd_feed', NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(212): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('wd_feed')
#8 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(586): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->_prepareDataForTable(Object(Whirl_Productrecommendation_Model_Wdfeed), 'wd_feed')
#9 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(449): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_prepareDataForSave(Object(Whirl_Productrecommendation_Model_Wdfeed))
#10 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Whirl_Productrecommendation_Model_Wdfeed))
#11 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/community/Whirl/Productrecommendation/Model/Observer.php(60): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Whirl_Productrecommendation_Model_Observer->addProductViewedEntry(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Whirl_Productrecommendation_Model_Observer), 'addProductViewe...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_control...', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php(354): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_control...', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(121): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product->initProduct(83, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#17 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(83, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#18 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#19 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#20 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /var/www/html/dilsebol2/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Comment: check your database. Table `wd_feed` is not found in database `dilsebol2`

Comment: From your error I can see it is trying to find the table `dilsebol2.wd_feed` where I assume `dilsebol2` is the prefix where as in code its searching only for `wd_feed` without prefix.

Comment: @MineshPatel you're right but that table is created by 3rd party extension it's not created at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a table called **wd_feed** however, this table does not exist in the database called **dilsebol2**.
The query that is being ran is `DESCRIBE wd_feed`.

You could try to manually create the tables, or find where and why it calls a describe.

Comment: No problem, would be nice if you could mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is Pointing that table 'dilsebol2.wd_feed' does not exist.

do like this

```
  show tables like '%wd_feed%';
```

If table is not avaialble than your install scrit of module has not worked.

If your table has not any data than

```
 select * from core_resource where code like '%wd_feed%';
```

and delete that entry re-run admin.

It may resolve the issue.